# Speed test of C# multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I would like to run a test against C# (I want to compare it's run speed to another language).
What I would like to do is create 100,000 threads in a chain, have each wait for a value from the thread before it, when it gets the value add 1 and pass the value to the next thread.
The idea is to see how quickly it can create those threads and add up to 100,000.
I have no idea how to write that code.  I can do pieces of it like threading and timing, but I'm not sure how to string them together.

***EDIT***
It seems I also get to learn about my deficiencies in knowledge when it comes to Threading.  So let's assume that Thread Pooling (or some other low level method) is comparable, can anyone show me examples of that?

Comment: Creating 100.000 threads ... don't even go there.

Comment: It sounds like something you would never do in production code... so why test it?

Comment: This is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it. You never want to create anywhere near that many threads. If you need a bunch of threads, the right thing to do is to make a thread pool and pull threads out of the pool. You already know that thread creation is heavyweight, so what will you learn by doing this? Just that allocating and deallocating the stack for those threads is expensive and should be avoided. If you want to measure the performance of different threading techniques, the thing you really want to measure is the performance of the Task Parallel Library.

Comment: I just want to do it as a comparison vs "Go" the google language.  In the example where they do it, it takes 1.5 seconds to run and I wanted to compare it.

Comment: A Task would be more appropriate for this kind of work than a Thread.  See the TPL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: @James: Go doesn't use real (operating system) threads, it uses "goroutine" threads, which are not the same thing.  C# has no built-in equivalent (yet).  (The new `async` stuff that will be in C# 5 is designed to serve a somewhat similar purpose.)

Comment: @James: But *why* do you want to compare two languages at doing something that no sensible person would ever do? If you have that many threads to create in C# then you would *always* go with a pooling solution, or even better, by allowing the TPL to decide for you how to manage parallelism.

Comment: For the same reason I used a separate thread for each bouncing ball in my MFC class, just to see what happens. And after trying it out I was really surprised at how cheap spinning up new threads actually is.

Comment: @Eric: Why do people do Code Golf?  Because they want to see what they can do with languages.  I don't understand why this is a bad question to ask.  Also, a current coworker of mine has actually done something like this to test out a piece of his code for a server and he said 100,000 threads can be done (using threadpooling).  He is trying to extract the code to show me right now.

Comment: Ah, yes, and Daniel points out, you are not comparing apples with apples. Again, you really should be measuring equivalent things. If Go uses a low-thread solution for asynchrony then you should compare it against the equivalent C# low-thread solution, not a completely crazy high-thread solution. Remember, *threads are not a unit of work*.  *Tasks* are a unit of work. If you want to compare the performance of two asynchronous-work systems, don't bring threading into it.

Comment: @James: If a hundred thousand people all read the same ten copies of a magazine, that doesn't mean that a hundred thousand copies of the magazine were printed. Thread pooling and thread creation are essentially *opposites*. The whole point of thread pooling is to *avoid* creation of threads.

Comment: @Eric (about magazines) : Awesome example and great way to explain that.  Thanks!

Comment: Thread creation time is virtually irrelevant in 'real' apps that usually create all the threads they need at app startup. Also, not sure what you mean by 'passing' - a term usually reserved for parameters in function calls - something impossible between threads - they have to communicate by signalling via. the OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This scenario is exactly what the TPL is designed to achieve, in particular `ContinueWith`, or `await` in C# 5 parlance. Note that async != threading (although they are related), but the point is that you are actually trying to execute 100k *tasks*, not 100k *threads*. These two concepts are different. The TPL is the right way to do this. Always use an appropriate tool for the job.

I'll happily whip up a TPL example if you want... something not too far to:

```
var root = new Task<int>(() => 0);
var end = root;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++)
{
    end = end.ContinueWith(last => last.Result + 1);
}
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
root.Start();
end.Wait();
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("{0} in {1}ms", end.Result, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Do it for everyone, Marc. I know you want to ;)

Comment: @jgauffin indeed I do - but I'm on mobile at the moment - no PC. Eric and Jon can probably write valid async code in a textbox; I need a compiler :)

Comment: Please do Marc (or anyone else that can)

Comment: @James TPL example added; certainly better than killing the machine

Comment: @Marc, for anyone just looking at the ms, you run 1M tasks, not 100k. On my machine yours is 100k / 100ms, just like svick reports.

Comment: @Henk - good spot! For some reason, I always start at 1M in my aggressive tests - I guess my fingers slipped and added that fatal 6th zero.#

Comment: @Henk - you must have a beast of a machine ;p Locally I can summon 160ms

Answer (score 3):

OK, just for discussion purposes and not a real benchmark at all:

```
const int numberOfTasks = 100000;
int total = 0;
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
Parallel.For(0, numberOftasks, (i) => Interlocked.Increment(ref total));
var elapsed = watch.Elapsed;
```

This includes joining all Tasks and aggregating exceptions.

On my dual core laptop it takes 0.004 seconds in Debug mode.

Comment: doesn't quite measure the same thing, though: " in a chain, have each wait for a value from the thread before it, when it gets the value add 1 and pass the value to the next thread"

Comment: Marc, I know that. But the final number is the same :)

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear to me what exactly do you want to measure. You could easily whip up a code that uses `Task`s to do the computations:

```
var initial = new Task<int>(() => 0);

var task = initial;
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    task = task.ContinueWith(t => t.Result + 1);

var watch = new Stopwatch();

watch.Start();

initial.Start();

task.Wait();

watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
```

This code looks like the one you want and on my computer it takes about 0.10 s to execute it. This is almost useless number though, mostly because this doesn't test multi-threading at all. All of the tasks run on the same thread, one after another, because there is absolutely no need for parallelism in your example.

Of course, this doesn't show that C# is a better language than Go. All this shows is that you should test things like this on examples that at least resemble something someone would find useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your main function, create those threads in a loop without running them. In the meantime make the thread i wait thread i-1 to exit. Once the loop is finished, simply start the first thread (e.g. thread 1) you created (waiting nothing but waited by thread 2). They will be started one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to crash Windows.

You'll need to create a class that has a `Thread` member variable and uses `Linked Lists`.

In your class constructor, it should take the `Thread.ID` of the previous thread and your `Count` index.

When your class is created, it's constructor would need to check the `Count` value, and create another class if it is under 100,000.

That'd be nasty, though. You might mess up your computer.

Comment: It won't crash windows, you'll just get an out of memory exception.

Comment: LOL. Yeah. I'm waiting to see Gravell's answer, though.

Answer (score -1):

using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

```
    static int X;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const int INT_Constant = 1000;
        var threads = new Thread[INT_Constant];

        for (var i = 0; i < INT_Constant; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(RunThread);
        }

        threads[0].Start();
        for (var i = 1; i < INT_Constant; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Start(threads[i - 1]);
        }

        threads[INT_Constant - 1].Join();

    }

    static void RunThread(object state)
    {
        var previousThread = (Thread)state;
        if (previousThread != null)
            previousThread.Join();

        X += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Thread # " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " updated X to " + X);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Avoid prints for speed tests.

Comment: This works because the threads finish faster than it can build new ones. If you want to build all the threads at the same time see my other answer.

Answer (score -1):

using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

```
    static int X;
    static object SyncRoot = new object();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const int INT_Constant = 1000;
        var threads = new Thread[INT_Constant];

        for (var i = 0; i < INT_Constant; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(RunThread);
        }

        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            threads[0].Start();
            for (var i = 1; i < INT_Constant; i++)
            {
                threads[i].Start(threads[i - 1]);
            }
        }

        threads[INT_Constant - 1].Join();

    }

    static void RunThread(object state)
    {
        var previousThread = (Thread)state;
        if (previousThread != null)
            previousThread.Join();
        else
            lock (SyncRoot)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting now");
            }

        X += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Thread # " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " updated X to " + X);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: This one will throw an Out of Memory exception on my computer if you set the constant to 10,000 threads.